# django admin login suddenly demanding csrf token

Tags: django

I was logging into my django admin console easily a few minutes ago. I must have changed something somewhere that caused this error when logging in as superuser:

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

This error caught me off guard as I was logging in all night. Why would I suddenly need a csrf token for admin login? You would think the sign in form already has that. This is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.models import Image, Category, UserProfile

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display    = ["__unicode__", "title", "created"]

admin.site.register(Image, GenericImageAdmin)

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display    = ["category"]

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

Comment: I cleared the database w flush, and now my app is working and I can make new users and whatnot. But I cannot use the admin. If I do "createsuperuser" I get an admin user and it complains that user does not have a userprofile. This is true, making a superuser doesn't make userprofile- userprofile is made when I make a new fake user in my registration page

Comment: from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    blurb = models.CharField(max_length=800, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

Comment: it wont let me make it look like code

Comment: My apologies for the snark. I didn't expect the question asker to be adding code in comments (edit your question instead). For future reference, surrounding with backticks (`) indicates code in-line (both in comments and posts)

Comment: @Basic you're fine, I'm complete SO noob. Any snark was deserved haha

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Admin login normally does require a csrf token, but that's normally all taken care for you.

1. Check your browser's cookies to see if there is a csrf token present
2. Try clearing cookies and refreshing
3. If you are using Django 4.0, you may need to add this line to your `settings.py` file: `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.mydomain.com','https://*.127.0.0.1']` (making the appropriate changes). In 4.0, they started checking the origin header unlike in previous versions. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285834/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-reason-given-for-fail/70326426#70326426) for suggesting this solution.
4. Check to make sure you have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in your middleware
5. Check that you're either on `https` or you have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False` (which is the default) in settings, otherwise your csrf cookie exists but won't be sent. Purge your cookies after changing `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE`.

Comment: so after debugging an issue not anywhere near related to django.admin, it works again. Wish I could add insight for other django noobs, but the only thing I did was manually add UserProfiles (connected like usual) to my users from createsuperuser

`class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)`

Comment: I have a registration page where new users sign up and are forced to make userprofile from the registration form, now when I make create super user from manage.py command is there a prettier pythony way to give them a blank userprofile instead of manually doing it in shell then hitting save()? It seems very 1995 what I'm doing

Comment: Assuming you have a standard userprofile defined in settings.py, it should be auto-created when you do create super user, if memory serves.

Comment: @ubadub added another reason to your list, hope you don't mind (`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False`).

Comment: Yes, I am on https. And now?

Comment: 1. There was. So, I removed it.
2. Did that.
3. Yes.
4. My code does not explicitly set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE. Tried setting it to False explicitly. No change.

Comment: i'm using django 4.0 and for me adding ```CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.mydomain.com']```  in `settings.py` works for me

Answer (score 97):

for new users facing this issue after upgrading to Django +4.0 you need to add `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=['https://*.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM']` to `settings.py`

thanks to the below answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70326426/2259546

Comment: I guess the ALLOWED_HOSTS wasn't good enough anymore...

Answer (score 5):

This error was appearing for me when I had not set CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN in my settings_local but it was set in my main settings.py.

In my case I set it to the local host eg

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a csrf token to your context in the login view and in your template add in the hidden div for the csrf token.  Ensure you have django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in the middleware section in your settings.py.

Then add @csrf_protect to your views to do with login.  It is also possible you tried to login with incorrect credentials - you need @csrf_protect on the logout view in your app's views.py you call on the appropriate uri for login/logout etc. in urls.py also.  My logout simply calls logout(request) then calls HttpResponseRedirect('') which is probably not perfect but it does me for my needs for now.

Answer (score 3):

As a security measure, I had `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` in my settings. Trying to log into admin via localhost where there isn't HTTPS threw the forbidden error.

Set it to `False` to get it working on localhost

Comment: Actually, I faced the same problem. The site only would load via HTTPS,  The solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This could also happen when you are already logged in into your website hosted on a url different than admin. And then try to login into your admin panel in a new tab.
Try to open the admin panel in a different window.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was solved by changing the setting:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

to

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'http')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your site in incognito mode.

There is a good chance that it could be your browser cookie, the above test will iron out that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with the containers on Kubernetes, where Traefik completes https, then Nginx only forwards HTTP (although URL is https) and then Django needed in `settings.py`

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

So that it could match `https://example.com` (otherwise I got the CSRF error). For `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` I had to add `'http://10.244.1.*'` which is internal kubernetes IP and then I need to put in Nginx configuration     `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;` . Strange combination if you ask me, but it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I used to have the same problem every time when I was using my default environment, and then using a virtual environment worked for me. It works every time. If you don't know how to create a virtual environment, here's how you do it:

1. Just create a virtual environment in your project's directory by
   running the command `virtualenv theNameYouWannaGiveYourEnvironment`.
2. Then activate your virtual environment by using
   `theNameYouWannaGiveYourEnvironment/bin/activate`(on Linux, I think it works for Mac Os too, but it's different for Windows).
3. After that, just install Django by `pip install django` and all the other requirements for your application to run.

Alternatively, you can also use Anaconda to create your virtual environment and install all your requirements. Just refer to this documentation if you wanna use anaconda: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html