# CSRF verification failed on a fresh django project's admin login

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I just created a project in django using `django-admin startproject xyz` and then, I navigated to the project folder and created a superuser using the command `python manage.py createsuperuser` on my Ubuntu's terminal and I filled the details. After this, I started the server by `python manage.py runserver` and I went to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ on my browser and everything seemed to be normal:

[Image of the admin login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsokf.png)

Then, I clicked on the submit button after entering the admin credentials and this showed up:

[Image of the 403 Forbidden page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wMn8.png)

Please help.

Comment: [UPDATE] Guys, I just got the solution. I had to disable CSRF validation as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458166/how-to-disable-djangos-csrf-validation . I know that this method isn't so reliable, but it worked for me/

Comment: Presumably your browser has a cookie named `csrftoken` from a previous installation associated with `localhost`. Just remove it and reload.

Answer (score -1):

Stackoverflow throws this [django admin login suddenly demanding csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573163/django-admin-login-suddenly-demanding-csrf-token). I'm sure one of the solutions will work for you.