# django admin panel deploy on server Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, docker, heroku

I'm on course Test-Driven Development with Django, Django REST Framework, and Docker (Michael Herman). My problem is that in a locally running container, the admin panel opens without problems, but the container placed on heroku gives an error (Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.) .. Where to look? Thanks!

Comment: Request the parts of the code you need

Answer (score 20):

I found a solution. The fact is that in `Django 4.0` you need to add
`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=['https://*.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM']` to `settings.py`

Thanks to Zeedia:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70572093/18351480